# css class "currency-input" is not allowing select text in textbox on tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have two input boxes in my web page , second text box is pre populated text whatever inserted in first textbox (by javascript). I am facing one issue is like when i move tab button from first textbox to second textbox then in chrom , firefox prepopulated value of scond textbox is highlighted but in IE text is not highlighting , only cursor blinking in to the box.

There is a css class "currency-input" if i remove it from textboxes then it selection of text on tab start working in IE as well.But i need this css class. Is there way to keep currency-input css class and on tab click text selection work in IE?

here is my textboxes:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="TransactTextBox" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="From Amount  " aria-label="From Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="8" onkeyup="sync()" onclick="this.select();"/>
 <input type="text" runat="server" id="TransactTextBox_2" class="form-control currency-input" placeholder="To Amount " aria-label="To Amount" data-allownegative="true" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="14" tabindex="9" onlcick="this.select();" />
```

Sync() javascript function :

```
 function sync() {
        var TextBoxA1 = document.getElementById('<%= TransactTextBox.ClientID %>');
        var TextBoxA2 = document.getElementById('<%= TransactTextBox_2.ClientID %>');
        TextBoxA2.value = TextBoxA1.value;
    }
```

Comment: Good to mention the `currency-input` class in your question

Comment: @ThilankaD - you got the correct point , i just updated this class with this.focus and now its started highlighting the text even in IE as well.